# Configuring a secondary NIC in Azure with an Internet Gateway

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, gateway

I have a VM in Azure with two NICs. Each NIC has its own subnet.
Azure only lets the Primary NIC have a public IP address. It appears that unless you have a public IP address a NIC cannot access the Internet but I need both to have Internet access.

Config details: 
The Primary NIC is on subnet 10.0.0.0/24 with Gateway 10.0.0.1. This subnet is for the Management Network. I need this to ssh into the machines for host administration purposes.
The second NIC is on subnet 203.0.113.0/24 and requires a gateway with IP address 203.0.113.1 but I of course cannot configure that. This subnet is for the application and the application requires Internet assess.
[image: Network Layout]

I am not a networking expert so I struggling to work this one out. In fact looking at the diagram maybe the Primary NIC should be the Provider Network... ???

I *think* I need to create another VM and make it the Internet gateway - but maybe there is another way in Azure.

Finally, I do not have a VPN set up into Azure. I am SSHing in via the public Internet - and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: Azure will support assign multiple IP addresses to virtual machines. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal

Answer (score 0):

We have now added the ability to have a public IP on all your NICs, including the secondary NICs. It is currently in preview, more information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell) about how to get access. Hope this helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell